# Mule private flows and separation of concerns

Tags: exception, mule

I have a requirement which I want to solve using Mule. My flow design follows like:

- A **main-flow** with request-response HTTP inbound endpoint. After applying couple of transformations on the current payload this main flow invokes two private flows namely **private-flow1** and **private-flow2**, which are mule private flows whose processing strategy is synchronous.
- The **private-flow1** invokes an external service using request-response HTTP outbound endpoint.
- The **private-flow2** places the response from the external service on Database using Database Connector.

If there is any exception in each of the private flows, I want to handle them in the corresponding private flow itself using Catch Exception Strategy.

I have this design to separate the concerns, so that each flow performs a single responsibility.

Suppose there is an exception like IOException, SQLException or any, in any one of the private flows, **how can I re-throw my custom exception**, for example, org.mycompany.CustomException including the underlying cause. So **main-flow** will have to handle only org.mycompany.CustomException and build the related exception response.

Say for example, if **private-flow1** throws org.mycompany.CustomException which is caused by IOException, the realted exception response would be:

*{"exceptionMessage" : External Service unavailable, "exceptionCode" : 101}*

and, if **private-flow2** throws org.mycompany.CustomException which is caused by SQLException, the realted exception response would be

*{"exceptionMessage" : Database unavailable, "exceptionCode" : 102}*

Answer (score 1):

Each private flow will have their own exception strategy and you can throw an exception using Groovy component from the flows ..

Here is a link how to do it :- [How do I force an exception in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689573/how-do-i-force-an-exception-in-mule/18691490#18691490)

for custom exception create java-class which would extend DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy

**Update:-**
An example to use **custom-exception-strategy**:- [Why is Mule exception strategy so chatty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941153/why-is-mule-exception-strategy-so-chatty)

Comment: Is groovy scripting component the only available options to re-throw an exception?

Comment: If you are planning for custom exception you can use java class or Groovy for re throwing custom exception

Comment: Can you please provide an example or link to create custom exception using java-class which would extend DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy? And how to use this java-class inside a flow.

Comment: I am not sure extending CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy will re throw custom exception?

Comment: As you suggested, I did like this:  `<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy"><scripting:component doc:name="throw-custom-exception"><scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new org.mycompany.mule.CustomException()]]></scripting:script></scripting:component> </catch-exception-strategy>` . 

But it throws a new error: `org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: Failed to dispatch message to error queue after it failed to process.`

Comment: That is wrong ... Throw the exception in the flow and use catch exception strategy to catch it .... don't put it inside catch block ....do like the following :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932785/mule-accessing-the-exception-stack-and-logging-a-particular-part